# Exporting the data from postgres to .txt or csv multiple times by using copy function

Tags: postgresql, csv

I have created procedure, I wanted to the output to copy to .txt or.csv.
I have used copy function to do for that.

For example `get_count_new1` is the function name

```
COPY( select * from get_count_new1('2014-03-14','2014-03-17')) 
TO 'C:\test1\ab12344.txt';
```

If i execute this it will work fine, but if I change the date and execute the above, it will run and its over writing the previous data present in the .txt file.

I wanted it to append the value with the existing data. how to get the data with the new value along with the previous data?

Comment: where to use append in the above sql statement? I searched in the [http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-copy.html](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-copy.html) but dint find.

Comment: There is no append option for `copy`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name , but how to over come this problem? Please help me out.